# Post data in a EditText to external database placed in web server

Tags: android, database

I'm new to android.I need to post data in a EdiText to server database table.Data is sent to a php page.SQL Query is in that page.Please guys help me out.I don't know how to do this.pleaseeee...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of sending some text data to the PHP script:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", text));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text2", text2)); //you can add as many you need

try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://yourserver.com/script.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();               
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", e.toString());
        return false;
        //Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```